# Chess UCI get position as FEN

Tags: chess, uci

Trying to code a chess engine for the first time. I have connected my engine to the cutechess GUI [cutechess](https://cutechess.com/). Currently my engine is receiving the current position from cutechess as something like: position startpos moves e2e4...etc

But looking at this from the UCI protocol:

[image]

I think my engine should have the option to receive the current position as a FEN string from cutechess GUI instead of position startpos moves e2e4...etc.

Debug Log:

- ChessBot(0): uciok
- ChessBot(0): isready
- ChessBot(0): readyok
- ChessBot(0): ucinewgame
- ChessBot(0): position startpos
- ChessBot(0): position startpos moves f2f3
- ChessBot(0): isready
- ChessBot(0): readyok
- ChessBot(0): go wtime 300000 btime 300000 movestogo 40
- ChessBot(0): bestmove e7e5

Instead of my engine receiving: position startpos moves f2f3

How do I instead receive position fen (fenstring)?

UCI protocol: [UCI Protocol](https://www.wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html)

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8462/uci-engine-state-notion

Comment: Also check https://gist.github.com/DOBRO/2592c6dad754ba67e6dcaec8c90165bf#file-uci-protocol-specification-txt for the TXT representation of the specification, which actually shows the `<fenstring>` token for the `fen` option.

Comment: Instead of starting from the starting position, edit the board in the GUI to make it start from a custom position.

Comment: Actually you can basically do nothing. The engine should be able to receive ```position startpos```, ```position startpos moves [moves]```, ```position fen [fen]``` and ```position fen [fen] moves [moves]```. It's the GUI decision. But most GUI send ```position startpos moves [moves]```, as the list of moves can be useful for the engine to detect a repetition or to change its time management based on the number of moves.

Comment: @LittleCoder Thanks. I did eventually figure it out, but this is what I was looking for.